# How do I specify the Application Insights key in the bot config file

Tags: botframework

I'm using MS Botframework v4 and want to set my Application insights key in the bot-config.

The relevant snippet from my .bot file looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "appInsights",
    "tenantId": "uuid",
    "subscriptionId": "uuid",
    "resourceGroup": "Development_UKS",
    "name": "my-bot",
    "serviceName": "",
    "instrumentationKey": "uuid",
    "applicationId": "uuid",
    "apiKeys": {"uuid"},
    "id": "4"
},
```

What is the correct syntax to use to insert my appinsights API key?  I don't know what key to use for the value and I can't find any examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Botbuilder is expecting a C# standard dictionary to be deserialized from that.  The following works just fine:

```
"apiKeys": {
     "0": "whatever-uuid-needed"
},
```

Comment: you should accept it. if this answer works for you. This can indicate someone who has the same question.